# ACSL specification for a possibly infinite C function

Tags: frama-c, language-specifications, acsl

I am trying to specify the behavior of external functions, more precisely, their termination. The ACSL documentation says that the `\terminates p;` property specifies that if the predicate `p` holds, then the function is guaranteed to terminate, but specifies nothing when `p` doesn't hold. It also explains that a function that never returns could be specified by:

```
//@ ensures \false ; terminates \false ;
```

Moreover ACSL provide a property `\exits p;` to specify the postcondition in case of abrupt termination. So I am wondering if:

```
//@ ensures \false ; exits \false; terminates \false ;
```

would specify that the function always loop forever ?

Moreover, what does the specification :

```
//@ ensures p ; exits q; terminates \false ;
```

means regarding to possible infinite loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specification is the closest one that can amount to say that a function is looping forever, but I still see two corner cases left:

1. *Run-time error*: you can always say that they are taken care of elsewhere (`WP`+`genassigns` or `Value`)
2. *longjmp*: I'm afraid there is currently nothing in ACSL to specify something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About run time error, I thought of that but you cannot expect specifying RTE, can you ? About longjump, I think that I can ignore them for the moment. Thanks again.